# Get owner entry from fieldtype

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I have a custom fieldtype (used within Neo block) and I need to know the ID/content of entry it belongs to, when editing the entry.

I need to both populate field values based on value in other field (if present) and also perform validation on save by comparing with other fields in same entry.

So I need to know the entry content (or at least entry ID so I could fetch those) within `getInputHtml` and `validate` functions.

I know I could use `$this->model` and `$this->element` but those don't seem to provide any data related to entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that entry can be accessed with `$this->element->owner`